# How to access WSL path direct from windows API?

Tags: windows, powershell, winapi, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wmic

I have windows10 and WSL environment.
Suppose I want to access a WSL file via windows API ,eg

```
HFILE WINAPI OpenFile(
  _In_   LPCSTR lpFileName,
  _Out_  LPOFSTRUCT lpReOpenBuff,
  _In_   UINT uStyle
);
```

How can I access file in windows like these

```
OpenFile(L"/opt/file" ... )
```

instead of

```
OpenFile(L"\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\opt\\file" ... )
```

Can we use API or Windows mklink/driver remap ways to made it?

Comment: What's the problem using the second type of path?

Comment: @SimonMourier I do cross-platform coding. A Project file with lots of linux path upload to windows platform, I use samba to access it, and want to keep the simple linux path without change the origin Project file

Comment: There's no way you will access a WSL path without some WSL info. You'll need to abstract that using a macro, a function, like MyOpenFile("/opt/file") which will translate to whatever corresponds to the target platform. This is quite common in cross-platform code.